# Is it possible to use a subquery more than once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I was wondering if it was possible to use a subquery in SQL more than once.

For example:

```
with subQuery as (
select id from someTable1
)
update someTable2
set someValue = 1
where id in (select * from subQuery)

select * from someTable2
where id in (select * from subQuery)

...
```

As of right now, SQL throws an error on the `(select * from subQuery)` in the `select * someTable2` clause saying "Invalid Object Name subQuery". So is there a way to use subQuery more than once without having to add a table or run the query multiple times changing out the first statement?

Comment: You can't have two update statements in a single query.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes you can, I have done it many times before. And that is not the main purpose of this question. The question is whether you can use subQuery more than once, even with select statements

Comment: If you want to update multiple tables at once, you need to do `UPDATE sometable1 JOIN sometable2 ...`

Comment: @Barmar - again, I've used multiple update statements before and that is not my question. If you are so hung up on that, I can change the updates to selects, I just want an answer to my original question

Comment: Yes, you can use a CTE multiple times: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mQLYFYxxgBq8H9hLj7ZHPS/0

Comment: as I said in my post, I do not want to create a new table, I want to keep it as a subQuery

Comment: Who said anything about creating a new table?

Comment: Is your question about subqueries or about common table expressions?

Comment: I guess maybe because of naming error you might have got that error check again did you run the correct table or with clause name. Does that someTable2 exists when you are running

Comment: apologies, I misread the query you attached. But I do not want to do a join or anything because I want to complete multiple different actions and then create a report after the edits all in one fell swoop. See my edited post, with an update and then a select. I'm just looking for a way that can use that subQuery more than once

Comment: While David Brown's answer is an interesting use of OUTPUT- I don't think it actually answered your question at all- which was to perform multiple actions (so more than 1 action) then display a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CTE is in scope only for a single query, but a query can both UPDATE and OUTPUT data.  eg

```
with subQuery as (
select id from someTable1
)
update someTable2
set someValue = 1
output inserted.*
where id in (select * from subQuery)
```